# Pass value from NSMutableArray to a double variable

Tags: iphone, ios, nsarray

Is it possible to pass values from NSMutableArray to a double variable ? I know NSMutableArray contains object. Is there a way I can extract the single value?

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to use the [NSNumber](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class to encapsulate numbers. You can use `[NSNumber numberWithDouble:myDouble]` and `[number doubleValue]`.